# On the center of a finite group $G$ with a normal Sylow subgroup

Tags: finite-groups

Suppose nonsolvable finite group $G$ has a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup. I would like to know whether center of the group $G$ is nontrivial?

Comment: It can be, unless you assume something extra (such as $p$ being minimal for example).

Comment: -1: Before posting a question on finite groups, please check to see whether your question can be answered by considering the finite groups of order up to $6$.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: $G$ is nonsolvable.

Comment: @Simon: it is now.  It wasn't when I made my comment.  But I have removed the downvote.

Answer (score 3):

The group $A_5 \times D_{14}$ is not solvable, has a normal Sylow $7$-subgroup, and has trivial center.

More generally, take any nonsolvable group $H$ with trivial center, $p$ a prime that does not divide $|H|$ and $K$ any group with trivial center and a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup. Then $H \times K$ is nonsolvable, has a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup and trivial center.

So to generalize the first example, you could take $A_5 \times D_{2p}$ where $p \geq 7$ is prime.

Answer (score 2):

The centre might be trivial (e.g. $S_3$ with $p=3$) or it might not (e.g. $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ with $p=2$).

Comment: Your example is for solvable group. Is there any example for nonsolvable group? (the question edited)

Answer (score 1):

To modify Chris Eagle's answer so as to fit the new question:

Let $G$ be a noncommutative simple group of order prime to $3$.  (Such groups exist, as one can see by looking through the [list of finite simple groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_finite_simple_groups).)

Note that $Z(G_1 \times G_2) = Z(G_1) \times Z(G_2)$ and $n_p(G_1 \times G_2) = n_p(G_1) n_p(G_2)$, where $n_p(G)$ is the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$.

$\bullet$ If $G = \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \times G$ with $p = 3$, the center is nontrivial.

$\bullet$ If $G = S_3 \times G$ with $p = 3$, the center is trivial.

Comment: But none of these examples have a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup.

Comment: @m.k.: You're right.  I'll fix it.