# Finite group with a normal Sylow subgroup

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group such that it has a normal Sylow p-subgroup. Is there any non-trivial element in the center of $G$?

Comment: @DonAntonio: Thanks. The question edited.

Comment: [Relevant](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300391/on-the-center-of-a-finite-group-g-with-a-normal-sylow-subgroup).

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is *always* the unity element in the center, so I gather you meant "non-trivial" element, and counterexample: $\,S_3\,$ ...

What's its normal Sylow subgroup and why $\,Z(S_3)=1\,$ ?

Answer (score 1):

For $p = 2$, the alternating group $A_4$ should be a counterexample. For $p > 2$ you could try the dihedral group $D_{2p}$. There are nonsolvable examples for $p > 2$ (see the question linked in the comments), but none for $p = 2$ by Feit-Thompson.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that $S_3\cong D_6$, the dihedral group of order $6$. So this answer is, in some ways, a natural and rather neat extension of DonAntonio's answer.